# How can I do a recomp?

Tags: exercise, muscle, training, body-fat

I am 17, and I used to be really skinny, but I had great cardiovascular health. I decided to bulk up and I started bodyweight exercises and ate at a surplus. The thing is, I gained a lot of fat and muscle, and I don't want to lose the muscle completely while burning fat. I am 170 cm and during the summer, I was 52 kg; now I am 65 kg. I want to drop to 60 kg and do a recomp, I know recomp is possible only for beginners but I only exercised muscle for 5-6 months. When I was skinny I did go to a gym but I only got skinnier so yeah I think I can do it but I don't know how.

Comment: With a small calorie deficit (around 15% below TDEE), high protein intake (2g/kg) and an adequate program, you'll reach your target weight in 3-3.5 months while losing mininum lean muscle mass.

Comment: @NeriaNachum - Instead of commenting, you should make that an answer. Answering in comments is not what the system is designed for.

Comment: Without knowing body composition etc. it's difficult to provide safe, effective, meaningful advice. Aim to lose a ~0.2-.5 kg/wk at the most, keep your nutrient intake at safe levels, and don't stress about it. You're too young to stress about this, and rushing it while still developing isn't good.

Comment: For those, like me, confused by the terminology, a recomp is [recomposition](https://blog.myfitnesspal.com/the-basics-of-body-recomposition-how-to-lose-fat-gain-muscle-at-the-same-time/), the act of losing fact while gaining muscle.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reduce your calorie intake so you have a small calorie deficit (around 200kcal/day would be good, 500kcal/day as an absolute maximum) - this will facilitate the weight loss.
However at the same time you need to be very disciplined with what you eat, maintaining a high protein intake and continuing to work out is key to maintaining your muscle mass.

Be careful not to try and lose the weight too quickly - at 17 it is possible you are still growing, and your body needs the fuel to do so.