Not Sure If I'm Doing Body Recomp Right
Ok so on my weight loss journey i kinda ignored the warnings about getting "skinny fat". I basically was just in a calorie deficit but i was scared i'd get bulky if i worked out. I'm 5'3, 115 pounds, and have a bit of looser skin. I really want to lose that last maybe 15ish pounds of outer layer of fat and build up some muscle. So far the plan is do to 30 minutes of strength training 3x a week (i usually need 2 rest days between cause of doms) and the rest of the week i do walking/running (about 10k steps) for my rest days. As for intake i'm trying to get in 1400cals and 100g of protein a day. I have no experience with lifting or strength training so I wonder if i'm doing any of this right. Some feedback would be super helpful.

I’ve been trying to get bulky for years. It cannot happen by accident.

For recomp you shouldn't be in a large deficit, the goal is not to lose weight, just fat. The weight should be stable as you build muscle https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/28585/how-can-i-do-a-recomp

As stated above, the point of body recomposition is to not lose or gain weight, but maintain weight while converting fat mass into muscle mass. For your height, 115lbs is already a fairly healthy weight, 100lbs would you getting near the bottom end of the bmi scale and just isn't necessary. Skinnier isn't always necessarily healthier. For your height and weight, and assuming a moderate exercise level, you would be wanting to consume more like 1600cal. Eating calories at a maintenance level can have a better effect on physique improvement because the increase in muscle mass amplifies the noticeable weight loss and not being in a deficit will increase your energy, improving your ability to exercise and just making your life nicer and easier.
